# PayaraMicro doesn't support http range header?

Tags: html5-audio, payara-micro

My webapp running on Payara-Micro is a tool to listen to audio files and navigate freely through them using the javascript `currentTime` property.
So the browser has `<audio src="...">` tags and to get the audio file, it sends http `GET` request to the server with the header `Range: bytes=0-` 
Unfortunately Payara in response doesn't returns `206` code and `Content-range: bytes 0-881403` but it returns `200` and this has the effect that when I use `currentTime=10` for exemple, the `currentTime` becomes equal to 0!

Previously this app was running in PHP with an apache server and apache was supporting the `range` header. 
Is it possible to configure PayaraMicro or Grizzly to support `range` request ? Or If I put an Apache server in front of PayaraMicro it will work ? 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but could it be that you need to add a custom HttpHandler to your webapp that handles the range requests? Cf. here https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=Vidada-Project%2Fvidada-desktop%2Fvidada-desktop-master%2Fvidada.server%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fvidada%2Fserver%2Frest%2Fstreaming%2FSeekableHttpHandler.java#

Comment: Thank you I'll try this but I don't get exactly if I can add this HttpHandler on my app source. Which implies to add provided dependencies to my apps pom.xml of Grizzly and other stuff maybe.

Comment: At least after making some tests by putting an apache http server in front of Payara-micro doesn't resolve the issue. :-/

Answer (score 1):

Payara supports RFC-7233. I did a mistake: there was a filter in my code that removed the default response header for media files.
Here is the devil filter:

`public void doFilter(...
(...)
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest,servletResponse);
}`

Subject closed!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: "somewhere" means in your code or in some third party framework or network component?

Comment: I answered in my Answer post.